# Volume and Surface Area of Banana using Calculus

Tags: integration, area, volume, surfaces

I'm trying to find the volume and surface area of a curved surface which is similar to that of a banana using calculus, however I am having difficulty because normally, one would due this using a volume of revolution, but there is no straight axis through which the curves modelling the banana could be revolved. Could someone please give some suggestions as to how I could approach this?

Comment: We need to know what your banana looks like.

Comment: Is your banana-like surface defined by a formula, or is it an actual banana?

Comment: For the volume: If you choose a convenient axis and are able to find an expression for cross-sectional areas perpendicular to this axis, then you can integrate the cross-sectional areas along the axis. For the surface area, I believe you can do the same with cross-sectional perimeters. But I may be missing something subtle in both of these suggestions.

Comment: A good approximation is to consider an incomplete torus. The width of the torus is $d$ and the radius of curvature is $R$. The banana includes only $\frac{\theta}{2 \pi}$ of the torus rotation.
The volume is therefore
$$
V=\frac{\theta}{2 \pi} \frac{\pi^{2} R d^{2}}{2}=\theta \pi R d^{2}
$$
The surface area is
$$
A=\frac{\theta}{2 \pi} 2 \pi^{2} R d+\frac{\pi d^{2}}{2}=\theta \pi R d+\frac{\pi d^{2}}{2}
$$

Comment: I am using an actual banana. I am looking for a method I could apply to that type of typical banana shape.

Comment: Then you gotta dip the banana in water and measure how much water it displaces

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle):

> If two bananas are such that every slice has the same area, then they have the same volume.

This way, if you can find the area of every slice of your banana, you can compute the volume of another banana, one which is a solid of revolution, that has the same area for each slice (so you would just integrate the area over the length).

[image: Cavalieri's banana]

I don't have an easy way to find the surface area, you might have to read up on surface integrals to do that.

Comment: Wouls you call it a banana split ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. This is a good one !!